# Nginx with cakephp - configuration problem

Tags: cakephp, nginx, url-rewriting

I am karthik. This is my first post here.

I have a vps running on centos with nginx server. I want a photogallery on my site. so i created a subdomain clicks.example.com. I am using a flash template called [whitespace cms](http://www.heikowaechter.com/#/?page=template) which uses cakephp. The problem is with the rewrite rules. I am not able to figure out the root directory.

This is my configuration file.

```
server { 
    listen       80;
    server_name  clicks.example.com;
    access_log /home/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log   /home/www/example.com/logs/error.log;
    rewrite_log on;

    # rewrite rules for cakephp
    location / {
      root   /home/www/example.com/clicks/fotoblog/app/webroot/;
      index  index.php index.html;

      # If the file exists as a static file serve it 
      # directly without running all
      # the other rewite tests on it
      if (-f $request_filename) { 
        break; 
      }
      if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
        break;
      }
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/www/example.com/clicks/fotoblog/app/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I think i am messing up with subdomain and root of cakephp. any help will be appreciated. I tried for 8 hours :) still no luck. When i use the above configuration i get blank page and sometimes i get a 502 bad gateway error.
Update: okay, 502 errors was due to nginx php-fpm problems. now when i access clicks.example.com i am getting redirected to the blackened of the cms. clicks.example.com/users/login.. [actually the backened should be clicks.example.com/fotoblog/users/login, do know where i am going wrong]

Comment: Check my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088717/issue-with-cakephp-application-running-on-nginx-1-0-8-subdirectory/8092482#8092482

Answer (score 0):

You're doing nothing wrong! I had a similar issue as well and was able to fix it after hours of researching and wasting time - I simply did a fresh install of a new Cake version and it solved my [nginx rewrite rule issues](http://www.endyourif.com/are-you-having-cakephp-and-nginx-rewrite-rule-issues/).