# CakePHP and Nginx configuration

Tags: cakephp, nginx

So I've been tasked with creating a site using CakePHP, so I downloaded the latest 2.2.3, and I need to configure it on my local nginx 1.2.4 server.

I have the `server_block` working, but for some reason I can't load any css. The test home page also reports that url rewriting isn't working properly.

I've been reading a number of articles and questions, but none seem to be able to solve the issue. So far I've referenced,

- [Issue with Cakephp application running on nginx 1.0.8 + subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088717/issue-with-cakephp-application-running-on-nginx-1-0-8-subdirectory)
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#pretty-urls-on-nginx
- http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2007/09/14/configuring-cakephp-to-work-with-nginx/
- http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2009/01/25/cakephp-nginx-configuration-update/
- http://kvz.io/blog/2010/02/24/cakephp-and-nginx/

My css links look like this,
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/david/Sites/example.com/css/cake.generic.css" />`

I need to figure out why Nginx isn't letting my CSS load. So far I can only find out that it's appending the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to all my links which obviously means my css will be incorrectly linked. I need to find out who to stop cakephp from picking up this extra information. Links are being passed into the HtmlHelper as follows `string '/Users/david/Sites/example.com//Users/david/Sites/example.com/css/cake.generic.css' (length=86)`

Currently my nginx config server block looks like the following.

```
server { 
    server_name  example.com;

    root   /Users/david/Sites/example.com/app/webroot/;

    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    listen       80;
    rewrite_log on;

    # rewrite rules for cakephp
    location / {
        index  index.php index.html;

        # If the file exists as a static file serve it 
        # directly without running all
        # the other rewite tests on it
        if (-f $request_filename) { 
            break; 
        }

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
            break;
        }
    }

    location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
        expires 6m;
    }
    location ~ ^/img/ { 
        expires 7d; 
    } 

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME example.com;
        include       fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

**FastCGIParams**

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $request_filename;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;

fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

Comment: when you look at the source code of the page in your browser and try to browse to the css link what happens? (also i'm assuming the link in the web page won't stay '/Users/dav...', right?)

Comment: @jagsler I get a 404, as the link is incorrect due to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` containing an absolute path. The issue lays with Nginx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've managed to figure out what the issue was.  It turns out that it's a variable in `core.php`

If you change `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));` to be `Configure::write('App.baseUrl', '/');` then it seems to all work and will route correctly to you css files.

My nginx config looks like the following.

```
server {
    listen   127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name  example.com.ukwm157;

    root /Users/david/Sites/example.com/app/webroot;
    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    charset utf-8;

    access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log main;
    error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    location / {

      index index.php index.html index.htm;

      if (-f $request_filename) {
        break;
      }
      if (-d $request_filename) {
        break;
      }

      rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;

    }

    # Static files.
    # Set expire headers, Turn off access log
    location ~* \favicon.ico$ {
      access_log off;
      expires 1d;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location ~ ^/(img|cjs|ccss)/ {
      access_log off;
      expires 7d;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files,
    # git & svn repositories, etc
    location ~ /(\.ht|\.git|\.svn) {
      deny  all;
    }

    location ~ .php?$ {
        #if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following configuration works for me with Cake 2.x

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name myprojecy.xyz;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

location / {
    root   /var/www/html/project-forlder/app/webroot;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (-f $request_filename) {
    break;
    }

    if (-d $request_filename) {
    break;
    }
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~ .*\.php[345]?$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
    /var/www/html/project-forlder/app/webroot$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you’re using a file path and not a URL.

Comment: Where exactly? Root should be a file path as it's configuring the location of the files on the server. If you mean in the CSS, this is handled by the CakePHP helper, and that takes it's configuration from the server.

Comment: You must have configured CakePHP incorrectly then, the URL for the stylesheet should be **/css/cake.generic.css** or similar.

Comment: Hence my posting a question. Cake hasn't actually been configured. It's just been unzipped into a folder. I think you misunderstand my question.

Comment: Best bet is to echo `CSS_URL` in your **/app/webroot/index.php** and see what the value is.